# Compiling the ffmpeg on iPhone?

Tags: ffmpeg, ios-simulator

I downloaded the iFrameExtractor sample code and try to compile it with the iPhone simulator version 3.1.3

The project shows the following errors (  http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/3245/66948298.png ) even thought I added *.a libraries to my project. All libraries was under the library searching path.

I guess it is a linking problem. Anyone can recommend to me a configuration for compiling ffmpeg on x86?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try compiling/building for iPhone Device instead of simulator, I think as the simulator does not has camera so you got the above errors while compiling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to test my program on simulator. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you will have to compile the ffmpeg for your simulator you can do that by using ./configure script and put the iPhoneSimulator.platform as the target platform and use arch i386 as architecture .